# Get Height of all Controls in a Table Row

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

Is it possible to get height of controls in row of table?

I want to get summation of Height of all controls in my table row:

e.g. for this:

```
Table.SetCellPosition(labelControl3, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 0));
Table.SetCellPosition(labelControl1, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 1));
Table.SetCellPosition(labelControl2, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 2));
Table.SetCellPosition(comboBoxSymbol, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, 1));
Table.SetCellPosition(comboBoxTimeFram, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, 2));
```

I want to get Height of labelControl3, labelControl1, and
 labelControl2 or can also be height of labelControl3, comboBoxSymbol
 and comboBoxTimeFram

(since there are total of 3row in the table)

Comment: i need to get all control row's height (not table height) to fix my panel's height

Answer (score 0):

This begs the question of WHY you need this - however you can iterate all controls for a panel, picking the ones in just the row you wish:

```
private static int GetControlHeights(TableLayoutPanel panel, int row)
{
    var height = 0;
    foreach (Control control in panel.Controls)
    {
        if (panel.GetRow(control) != row)
            continue;
        height += control.Height;
    }
    return height;
}
```